# Android Units Tests on Jenkins

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant, jenkins, break

We integrated android projects with Jenkins and executing unit tests automatically but have a problem. **Jenkins build is not broken even if the unit tests fail.**

We run unit tests with the following ANT targets: `clean emma debug install test`

I've found the [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) but it does not provide what i expect, it has a post build action parsing monkey test results but does not have one for unit tests.

**Is it possible to parse build output and change the build state depending on the parse result? Or any other way to break build when tests fail?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) with the following simple rule file, you add "Console Output Parsing" post build action and it can make the build instable if it finds any line matching the below regex `Failure in test.*`.

```
# match line starting with 'error ', case-insensitive
error /Failure in test.*/
```

It matched the following sample,

```
[exec] Failure in testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly:
[exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: test
[exec] at tr.com.turkcell.turkcellid.SecureStorageTests.setUp(SecureStorageTests.java:22)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
[exec] at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
[exec] at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
[exec] 
[exec] Failure in testDelete:
[exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: test
[exec] at tr.com.turkcell.turkcellid.SecureStorageTests.setUp(SecureStorageTests.java:22)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
[exec] at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
[exec] at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
[exec] 
[exec] Failure in testFail:
[exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: test
[exec] at tr.com.turkcell.turkcellid.SecureStorageTests.setUp(SecureStorageTests.java:22)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
[exec] at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
[exec] at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
[exec] 
[exec] Failure in testReadWithFalseEnryptionKey:
[exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: test
[exec] at tr.com.turkcell.turkcellid.SecureStorageTests.setUp(SecureStorageTests.java:22)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
[exec] at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
[exec] at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
[exec] 
[exec] Failure in testWriteRead:
[exec] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: test
[exec] at tr.com.turkcell.turkcellid.SecureStorageTests.setUp(SecureStorageTests.java:22)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
[exec] at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
[exec] at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
[exec] at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Android JUnit report test runner](https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report) in your test project, running your Android unit tests will result in a JUnit-compatible XML file being output.

When the test run has completed, you can extract the XML file from the emulator, and then let Jenkins' built-in JUnit support parse the file and alter the build result as appropriate.